# In OpenCV, is there any way to combine/separate image channels more efficiently than cv::merge and cv::split?

Tags: c++, opencv, filtering, fft

For a little background, I'm doing a whole lot of image filtering, using a bunch of complex-valued filters. 
I generate the real and imaginary parts of the filters separately (its more efficient that way), and store them in two separate arrays.

I followed [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html) on how to do dft's in opencv.

Basically, I have to

1. loop through my filters
2. call merge to combine the real and imaginary parts
3. perform a DFT
4. call split to separate real and imaginary again
5. compute the magnitude of the response

I do this, and its fairly slow. I initially thought I needed a faster FFT library, but based on Visual Studio's profiler, it turns out that cv::split() and cv::merge() take an order of magnitude more time than the actual DFT does. In fact, most of the running-time is spent in these two functions.

The whole split/merge thing seems a little redundant to me, and the fact that they're the most time consuming functions is pretty annoying. Is there a faster way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV matrices are stored in interleaved format. That means for a two channel image with channels A and B, a 4x1 matrix would be stored in the order `ABABABAB`. If you have two different planes, you have `AAAA` and `BBBB`.

It is probably hardest to convince the DFT to operate on non-interleaved input. However maybe you are able to store your filters as a two-channel matrix in the first place?

To compute the magnitude from the two channels, you can loop through all elements and call cv::norm on them or do the calculation yourself. You can speed that up further by using SSE and/or TBB.

So at least you save one of the conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

As far as starting with the filters as a two channel matrix, the main obstacle I encountered there is that I need to do complex element-wise multiplication to apply the filters. 

Once you merge, OpenCV doesn't have any notion of the numbers being complex, it's treated like just a 2 channel image. So I'd have to split them to perform the multiplication efficiently.

Comment: Well you could also go a totally different route by using matrices of `cv::Complex` type, the data of which you can feed directly into libfftw's dct method casted as `fftw_complex`.